# Intersections of ideals in polynomial rings with countably many variables

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Fix a field $k$ and let $R = k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$.  Say that an ideal $I \subset R$ is *generated in finite degree* if there exists a generating set $S$ for $I$ (possibly infinite) and an integer $n$ such that $S$ consists of elements of degree at most $n$.

Question: If $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ that are generated in finite degree, is $I \cap J$ generated in finite degree?

Comment: rather "in bounded degree"?

Comment: If this is true, then there exists $u(d)$ such that for every $n$ and every pair $I,J$ of ideals in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ generated in degree $\le d$, the intersection $I\cap J$ is generated in degree $\le u(d)$. I don't know if the latter statement is true but I would expect that it's known whether it holds (it's a natural issue, e.g., in the algorithmic problem of computing generators for an intersection of ideals).

Comment: Analogy for groups: a group $G$ is *boundedly presented* by a generating subset $S$ if the kernel of $F_S\to G$ is generated, as normal subgroup, by elements of bounded length. When $S$ is finite this means that $G$ is finitely presented (and does not depend on $S$). In this context the condition is not stable under intersection (even with a finitely generated free group), because there exist fibre products of 2 finitely presented groups that is not finitely presented. Anyway it's a very different context.

Comment: One more remark: if $I$ is generated by **monomials** of degree $\le d$ and $J$ by monomials of degree $\le e$, then $I\cap J$ is generated by monomials of degree $\le d+e$.